# Tourist and Marksman achievements not working

Tags: achievements, counter-strike-global-offensive

I did get popup message on the top left corner of the screen once saying that I unlocked/achieved the Marksman achievement, but it didn't save to my achievements list.

Also Tourist is not unlocking, I did play and win not just rounds, but entire matches in each and every Arms Race and Demolition maps that are given to chose from when playing offline with bots. I did play and repeat like for 2 days now and it's not unlocking.

Answer (score 1):

This is bug, shorttrain map is removed from the select list. You need to first load any demolition map and then from console write changelevel de_shorttrain and win a match.